# Path Bevel With Different Thickness Along the Vertices

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

Hi guys I have a path that generates a extrusion from a Bevel Object, but I need certain vertices with different bevel size. I tried to select the vertices, I can tilt them pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but I cannot change the size of the generated bevel in that specific point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to Shrink/Flatten a selected curve point while in edit mode for the curve:

[image]

This option is also available from the Toolshelf (<kbd>T</kbd>)